# auctex 11.86 in emacs 24: Don't know how to compile nil

Tags: errors, auctex

I run **emacs 24.2.50.1** and **auctex 11.86** on debian stable.
When i open a tex file with

```
$ emacs text.tex
```

Emacs shows the following line 38 times in the *Compile-Log* buffer

```
../../../../.emacs.d/elpa/auctex-11.86/font-latex.elc:Error: Don't know how to compile nil
```

[My complete emacs configuration](https://github.com/jonasstein/emacs-config) can be found online

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm also running **Emacs 24.2.50.1** on Debian stable (Squeeze) and I have
**the same issue**.  The difference is that I'm using **AUCTeX 11.85** from
the Debian repository, while you're using 11.86 from the ELPA.

I don't think your configuration is the issue, rather, it seems there
is a bug in the `font-latex` package, which is part of AUCTeX, which
recent versions of Emacs have stopped silently ignoring.  There is a
[thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gnu-emacs/2012-07/msg00172.html)
on the bug-gnu-emacs mailing list that describes the issue in more
detail.

The solution offered there is to upgrade `font-latex`.  Unfortunately,
the latest version of the `auctex` package in the Debian stable
repository does not include the patch for this bug, nor does 11.86,
which is the latest version in ELPA.  So, I'm not sure there's a
solution which will keep either your Debian or ELPA packages
consistent.

You might try directly installing a newer version of `auctex` from
either Debian `testing` or `unstable`.  However, there might be
dependency issues, so you could also try
[apt pinning](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences#Pinning), which
will help resolve the dependencies for you.

My solution was to download the latest version of `font-latex.el`,
byte-compile it, and replace the local files:

```
cd /tmp
wget 'http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/*checkout*/auctex/auctex/font-latex.el'
emacs -batch -f batch-byte-compile font-latex.el
sudo cp font-latex.* /usr/share/emacs/24.2.50/site-lisp/auctex/
```

Note that your path in the final command will be different, since I'm
using the version of AUCTeX from the Debian package.

Comment: the compilation fails. Will i need more files?
/tmp$ emacs -batch -f batch-byte-compile font-latex.el
[...]

In toplevel form:
font-latex.el:44:1:Error: Cannot open load file: tex

Comment: It sounds like it's having trouble locating the file `tex.el`.  You might try using `M-x byte-compile-file` from within Emacs instead, to ensure that your `load-path` is complete.  Then point it to the `font-latex.el` file you downloaded in `/tmp`.  This will produce the `font-latex.elc` file you need.

Comment: 1) Thanks to Jason! BTW, the problem still apparent in emacs 24.3 which has been released ~ 10 days ago.          2) I had the same problem as Jonas, and indeed, byte compiling "inside emacs" was easy and worked.